# Fullstack application how to run Angular2 with Express

Tags: node.js, express, angular

Hello i created 2 folders client and server. i put to my server, files generated by express . In client, i put files from Angular 2 [Qucistart tutoria](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html)l (without express angular work properly). I changed only layout.jade

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title Angular 2 QuickStart JS
    meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='styles.css')
    // 1. Load libraries
    // IE required polyfill
    script(src='../../client/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js')
    script(src='../../client/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js')
    script(src='../../client/node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js')
    script(src='../../client/node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.umd.js')
    script(src='../../client/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js')
    script(src='../../client/node_modules/@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js')
    script(src='../../client/node_modules/@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js')
    script(src='../../client/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js')
    script(src='../../client/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js')

    // 2. Load our 'modules'
    script(src='../../client/app/app.component.js')
    script(src='../../client/app/main.js')
  // 3. Display the application
  body
    my-app Loading...
    block content
```

when i started app.js from server. Angular dont change "my-app Loading..."

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: there is somethig, a few errors of the same type 
* Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

http://localhost:3000/client/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js

http://localhost:3000/client/node_modules/@angular/client/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js 

etc...

Comment: can you put your code on github and post the link here?

Comment: Hello, i solved that problem. Reason was very simple. In default express template, apk  looked for angular files in Server/public, but my files were in Client/app. Very thanks for trying help!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<my-app> Loading... </my-app>
```

Comment: still same problem